# Patch all functions in module with decorator

Tags: python

I have a python module with lots of functions and I want to apply a decorator for all of them. 
Is there a way to patch all of them via monkey-patching to apply this decorator for every function without copy-pasting on line of applying decorator?

In other words, I want to replace this:

```
@logging_decorator(args)
func_1():
  pass

@logging_decorator(args)
func_2():
  pass

@logging_decorator(args)
func_3():
  pass


@logging_decorator(args)
func_n():
  pass
```

With this:

```
patch_func():
  # get all functions of this module
  # apply @logging_decorator to all (or not all) of them

func_1():
  pass

func_2():
  pass

func_3():
  pass

func_n():
  pass
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd do that, but I don't think you should.  It's better to be explicit.  A find/replace should help solve the problem of having to type it for every function.

Comment: Not at that end, but when you `import` it you could iterate over the names the module exposes and patch them from there.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577742-apply-decorators-to-all-functions-in-a-module/)? It seems a little messy though.

Comment: @MarcelWilson I understand it, but this is not a only one mudule I should to patch. There is no class to add a mixin or something like this to do it more elegat way.

Comment: @Paul I get what you're going for and admit it's a clever idea. I worry the result will be convoluted/obfuscated for the next maintainer of that code.  I've learned that sometimes clever is not always better.

Comment: @Jezor thanks! Looks like something that I can use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm really not certain that this is a good idea. [Explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), after all.

With that said, something like this should work, using [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) to find which members of a module can be decorated and using [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) to manipulate the module's contents.

```
import inspect

def decorate_module(module, decorator):
    for name, member in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if inspect.getmodule(member) == module and callable(member):
            if member == decorate_module or member == decorator:
                continue
            module.__dict__[name] = decorator(member)
```

Sample usage:

```
def simple_logger(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("calling " + f.__name__)
        f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def do_something():
    pass

decorate_module(sys.modules[__name__], simple_logger)
do_something()
```

Comment: Looks very similar to what I need! Is there a way to pass args for decorator here? Because actually `@logging_decorator(args)` takes args to track these traces after.

Comment: A decorator with arguments is implemented as returning a standard decorator that wraps its argument - so using `decorate_module(module_to_wrap, logging_decorator(args))` should work. The limitation of my current approach is that, if `logging_decorator` lives in the module that you're trying to wrap, then `decorate_module` would try to decorate it, which might be bad. (`decorate_module` tries to not decorate the decorator, but since decorating-with-arguments generates new functions on the fly, that wouldn't work.)

Comment: So, actually my logging decorator lives in other packge, so  I belive this is not a problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I ain't gonna be pretty ... but you can list all functions using dir() after their definition. Then I can't think of a way to patch them without a wrapper function.

```
def patched(func):
    @logging_decorator
    def newfunc(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return newfunc

funcs=[f in dir() if not '__' in f]
for f in funcs:
    exec(f+'=patched(f)')
```